# PostgreSQL 13.3 installation on MacOS (Big Sur) failed with error: Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Tags: postgresql, macos

Downloaded the PostgreSQL installer from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads, and tried to install it on my new Macbook Pro running Big Sur.

The installation went fine, but it failed when executing the script `/Library/PostgreSQL/13/installer/server/initcluster.sh`.  I traced to the following script:

```
su - $OSUSERNAME -c "$INSTALLDIR/bin/initdb --pwfile $INSTALLDIR/installer/server/initdbpw.$$ --encoding=utf8 -A scram-sha-256 -U \"$SUPERNAME\" -D \"$DATADIR\""
```

Apparently, `su - postgres` does not work because the new service account `postgres` is not enabled for login.  Maybe this script should use `sudo -u postgres` instead of `su - postgres`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by updating the service account `postgres` as follows, so it is enabled for login:

```
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/postgres 'MyNewPassword'
sudo dscl . -read /Users/postgres
```

After you verify that the password of the account is no longer `"*"`, you can uninstall and reinstall PostgreSQL, so it can initialize the db, as long as you provide the same password for `postgres` when you re-install it.